# windows 10 entering grub rescue mode

Tags: boot, grub, windows-10

So yesterday after i installed windows 10 pro i notice that one i my partition was missing. I installed mini partition tools then i noticed that the drive was set to active and boot.first i tried to merge this drive to another one that was visible but that didn't work then i changed drive status too not (un) active this one didn't work too then i noticed that the partition didn't have a letter so i gave it one and the problem was fixed and everything seemed to be OK and i shutdown my computer till today that when  i turned it on it didn't boot and gives an error like this:

error: unknown filesystem

Entering rescue mode...

grub rescu>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO i fixed it.here is how

I put the windows 8 disk in the windows and boot the windows installer then i start repair windows clicked on repair startup and it got fixed.